# Create a customised receipt for a POS in Java

Tags: java, xml

I have developed a point of sale system. My problem is at the end i now need to create a customized receipt with the company logo and other things. I need to add the sale data and print the receipt. I strongly believe XML can be used for this though i dont know how. Any ideas will be highly appreciated

Comment: This seems *far* too broad to be an answerable question - what you need to do will depend strongly on the architecture of the system you've just developed, and on the specific requirements of how customizable it is.  I recommend you ask more targeted questions, e.g. "how can I represent a logo in text", or "how can I efficiently perform string substitutions" etc.

Comment: I would like to have a template for a reciept then embed the particulars for that particluar sale. How can i add these details to an existing template? But that is on approach am considering am open to other ideas.

Comment: @Magondu did you achieve this?

Comment: Yes. Quite a while back

Answer (score 1):

You're in luck... I did this exact same thing for my wife's business.  I used the build in print framework to get this working.  The class that do this is rather big, so here's the highlights:

Create a class that extends import java.awt.print.Printable

Create a Graphics2D object and print everything you want on that, then simply override the print()-method to look something like this:

```
@Override
public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {

    if (prevPage == pageIndex) {
        linesRendered = prevRendered;
    }
    prevPage = pageIndex;
    prevRendered = linesRendered;

    if (linesRendered >= lines.size())  {
        logger.fine("No further pages to send to printer.");
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    } else {
        // render here
        // ...
        return PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
}
```

The check is necessary as Java tends to call the method numerous times for the same page.  Then to print you, simply have to do:

```
public void printInvoice() {
    PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

    if (printJob.printDialog()) {
        try {
            InvoicePrinterHelper iph =
                    new InvoicePrinterHelper(...);
            printJob.setPrintable(iph);
            printJob.print();
        } catch (PrinterException pe) {
            System.out.println("Error printing: " + pe);
        }
    }
}
```

I took out quite a bit to save space, but this will work.  It took me ages to get it just right, but at least you don't have to dig as much as I had to.  Google the "printable" interface and you'll get numerous other examples.

I do recommend that you use Graphics2D and use anti-aliasing, otherwise the fonts look really bad.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Apache FOP](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/index.html), if you have the data in XML. With FOP you are able to change the style with ease and you are able to print to PDF, html pages...

Very useful tool for doing such things!